# ICarousel Menu infinite loop

Tags: iphone, xcode, carousel

I'm writting an Iphone application using with Icarousel. I used 2 carousel. When i scroll first, second scroll with first one and when i scroll second, first scroll with the second one.

I can do this correctly but I have a problem that is infinite loop.

```
   - (void)carouselDidEndScrollingAnimation:(iCarousel *)Carousel
{  
    if (Carousel == carouselSecond)
    {
        NSLog(@"***Second Scroll");
       [carouselFirst scrollToItemAtIndex:carouselSecond.currentItemIndex duration:2];
    }
    else if(Carousel == carouselFirst)
    {
        NSLog(@"***First Scroll");
    [carouselSecond scrollToItemAtIndex:carouselFirst.currentItemIndex duration:2];
    }
}
```

Display is
***Second Scroll
***First Scroll
***Second Scroll
***First Scroll
***Second Scroll
***First Scroll
***Second Scroll
***First Scroll
......

Comment: how come this becomes an infininte loop??

Comment: Because `carouselDidEndScrollingAnimation` gets called again when the second Carousel gets scrolled. You will need some flag which indicates if the second Carousel has already been scrolled or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an Integer variable to keep track of how many times the carousel has been scrolled. In your .h file add:

```
@property (nonatomic) NSUInteger numberofScrolls;
```

in `viewDidLoad`do this:

```
self.numberofScrolls=0;
```

and try this:

```
 - (void)carouselDidEndScrollingAnimation:(iCarousel *)Carousel
{  
self.numberofScrolls++;
if(self.numberofScrolls%2!=0){    
    if (Carousel == carouselSecond)
    {
        NSLog(@"***Second Scroll");
       [carouselFirst scrollToItemAtIndex:carouselSecond.currentItemIndex duration:2];
    }
    else if(Carousel == carouselFirst)
    {
        NSLog(@"***First Scroll");
        [carouselSecond scrollToItemAtIndex:carouselFirst.currentItemIndex duration:2];
    }
}

}
```

Let me explain what it does:
When the view loads, we set `numberofScrolls` to 0.
When user stops scrolling, the `carouselDidEndScrollingAnimation` gets called --> we increase `numberofScrolls` by 1 and carousel 2 gets scrolled to the same position. After carousel 2 is done with scrolling, `carouselDidEndScrollingAnimation` gets called again. We increase `numberofScrolls` once again (it is now 2). But this time we don't need to scroll the other view again and `self.numberofScrolls%2` becomes 0.